# android aapt doesn't work on arch linux

Tags: android, linux, cordova, build, archlinux

when ever I run the cordova/build, I get following ERROR:

```
 Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "../android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/aapt"
```

what should I do?

Comment: For anyone that is getting the same error on Scientific Linux 6.5, here is what I needed to install to solve this problem: sudo yum install glibc.i686 zlib.i686 libstdc++.i686

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by installing `lib32-glibc`.

> https://www.archlinux.org/packages/multilib/x86_64/lib32-glibc/

Answer (score 0):

I moved my Android Developer Tools (ADT) folder from Ubuntu's partition to Linux Mint's partition, but accidentally put in inside my web server's root folder and the permission of ADT's folders were set to 755, the files were set to 644 by my shell script to rebuild the permissions for my new web server.

After I moved ADT to my home folder and started using Android Studio, I got this problem.

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER -R /home/myusername/my-adt-folder
```

doesn't help.

GNU C Library was already installed by default. Not sure why it is related to this problem.

I decided to set 777 permission to ADT and it worked.

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /home/myusername/my-adt-folder
```

That's it.

It seems another system user in the system needs to access to android-4.4W/aapt file.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want `aapt` on Arch without the overhead/hassle of setting up ADT then you can try the solution that I presented on the *Android Enthusiasts* site [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/156520).